# UIAlertView exception in reachability

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uialertview, reachability

I'm new to iOS and I have a problem in dismissing an **UIAlertView** programmatically.

I declared the alert in .h file:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>{
    UIWebView *webView;
    UIAlertView *alert;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIAlertView *alert;
```

and in the .m file I use this alert to warn the user about internet connectivity:

```
@synthesize alert;
-(void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice
{
// called after network status changes
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
switch (internetStatus)
{
    case NotReachable:
    {
        NSLog(@"The internet is down.");
        self.internetActive = NO;
        alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network Unavailable" 
                                                         message:@"Internet connectivity could not be established!" 
                                                        delegate:self 
                                               cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
        [alert show];
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];

    }
}
```

}

Now, when the internet connection is down the alert appears. However, when the internet connection get established the program throws exception complaining about bad access to the object. Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Implement the UIAlertViewDelegate in your header file

2- use this method

```
 -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

}
```

inside this method dismiss the alert view based on the index of clicked button

Answer (score 0):

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
```

is called for all the other cases, and alert is not allocated any memory yet when the method is called. Also there is not point adding that line. 
Or you can modify your code like this.

1. Hold a reference to Alert (Its a very bad idea though)
2. In the switch condition check if alert box is diplayed and then call dismiss and release the alert view

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    default:
    {
        if (alert){
            [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
        }
    }
```

Assuming that "alert" is indeed 'nil' before you show it.